# Stop reading from STDOUT if stream is empty in BASH

Tags: bash, stdout

I am creating a script (myscript.sh) in BASH that reads from STDOUT, typically a stream of data that comes from cat, or from a file and outputs the stream of data (amazing!), like this:

$cat myfile.txt

> hello world!

$cat myfile.txt | myscript.sh

> hello world!

$myscript.sh myfile.txt

> hello world!

But I also would like the following behaviour: if I call the script without arguments I'd like it to output a brief help:

$myscript.sh

> I am the help:  I just print what you say.

== THE PROBLEM ==

The problem is that I am capturing the stream of data like this:

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    stream=$(cat <&0)
   
elif [[ -n "$stream" ]]; then
 
    echo "I am the help:  I just print what you say."
else
    echo "Unknown error."
fi
```

And when I call the script with no arguments like this:
$myscript.sh

It SHOULD print the "help" part, but it just keep waiting for a stream of data in line 2 of code above...
Is there any way to tell bash that if nothing comes from STDOUT just break and continue executing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that you are confusing stdout and stdin.

Answer (score 1):

There's always a standard input stream; if no arguments are given and input isn't redirected, standard input is the terminal.

If you want to treat that specially, use `test -t` to test if standard input is connected to a terminal.

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 && -t 0 ]]; then
    echo "I am the help:  I just print what you say."
else
    stream=$(cat -- "$@")
fi
```

There's no need to test `$#`. Just pass your arguments to `cat`; if it gets filenames it will read from them, otherwise it will read from standard input.

Comment: Dear @Barmar thank you very much!!! I've been struggling with this for weeks.  Nevertheless, i have noticed that the fourth line outputs the "help" even when called with the file as argument. Somehow cat is not getting that $1 is coming from the command line... I am figuring it out.

Comment: I just changed the condition so it only checks for a terminal when there are no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

First answer is to help yourself - try running the script with `bash -x myscript.sh`. It will include lot of information to help you.

If you specific case, the condition `$# -eq 0` was flipped. As per requirement, you want to print the help message is NOT ARGUMENT ARE PROVIDED:

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo "I am the help:  I just print what you say."
    exit 0
fi
# Rest of you script, read data from file, etc.
cat -- "$@"
```

Assuming this approach is taken, and if you want to process standard input or a file, simple pass '-' as parameter: `cat foobar.txt | myscript.sh -`

Comment: This will print the help message if you pipe input to the script.

Comment: @Barmar: you are correct, but the OP states two conflicting requirements: shouwnhelp when no arguments are provided, and process input from stdout (probably Stdin), when no arguments are provided. Not easy to decide which one he want. Assuming the board sitatuation should result in help message, to avoid incorrect usage, I chose the approach above.

Comment: He's just having trouble describing it, but the intention is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to @Barmar's solution.

However, it might be better to entirely avoid a situation where your program behavior depends on whether the input file descriptor is a terminal (there are situations where a terminal is mimicked even though there's none -- in such a situation, your script would just produce the help string).

You could instead introduce a special `-` argument to explicitly request reading from stdin. This will result in simpler option handling and uniform behavior of your script, no matter what's the environment.

Comment: thanks! But your suggestion is that "-" has to be used  when running the command but not hardcoded into the script. right?

Comment: Correct -- you'd either use `myscript.sh myfile.txt` or `cat myfile.txt | myscript.sh -`.